# Can't change the name of my generated .apk in Cordova 5.4.1

Tags: android, cordova, apk

I'm trying to change the name of my .apk file in Cordova 5.4.1 but everything I can find online only relates to older versions. from what I've read you need to manipulate the build.xml file but there is no build.xml file in 5.4.1. Simply renaming the .apk doesn't work either because it regenerates the default one every time it I run it.

please help!

Comment: yo can change the name of apk after `exporting` it from code, do you want to change it inside your project?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a build.xml solution, you can try with hooks. You should do a node script to locate the apk file and rename it, and put the script into the hooks/before_build/

some docs: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/appdev/hooks/

Ask if you need more info